# Replace Id with Value from a table

Tags: sql

I have a question, that I haven't yet found any solution, as I might be using the wrong term 'replace'.

I have two tables in my database. The first table contains a ID and a Number

```
Id | Number
1  | 234
2  | 45
3  | 98
```

The second table contains the ID's from the first table in a different column.

```
QuId | FWIId | FWAId
1    | 1     | 2
3    | 2     | 3
```

I need the second table, where the ID's are "replaced" with the numbers from table on.How should the query look like?

The result should look like this

```
Qu_Number | FWI_Number | FWA_Number
234       | 234        | 45
98        | 45         | 98
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  And `JOIN` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `join` the tables together, and pick which columns to display:

```
select  quid.number as Qu_Number
,       fwi.number as FWI_Number
,       fwa.number as FWA_Number
from    Table2 t2
join    Table1 quid
on      t2.FWIid = quid.Id
join    Table1 fwi
on      t2.FWIid = fwi.Id
join    Table1 fwa
on      t2.FWIid = fwa.Id
```

Comment: To be more precise: the "ON" actually means: "*For each of the rows in Table2 that are part of my result, scan for rows in Table1 that would meet the following condition*".

Comment: I edited my question. Add what the result should look like.

Comment: Example data sure helps to clarify your question! Updated the answer.

Comment: Your answer only replaces QuId with the right number from table 1.  But FWIId and FWAId are still the ID's. 
All values in table 2 are ID's, wich relate to table 1.
I need all ID's to be replaced with the right number from table 1

Comment: Updated again. A `join` is an `inner join` which filters out rows where no match is found. If you'd like `null` for unknown numbers instead, replace the `join`s with `left join`s.

Comment: Thank you! This worked! Didn't realize to make multiple joins on the same table!